# data.map is not a function in React all api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call simple apiCall in React but this is giving error as given below:

```
data.map is not a function
```

[Sandbox Url](https://codesandbox.io/s/apicall-ow61tl?file=/src/App.js)

My code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const apiCall = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json);
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data
        ? data.map((val) => (
            <div>
              <h2>{val.id}</h2>
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When you create your useState, provide it with a default value.
const [data, setData] = useState([]); Also ensure when you set the value for data, make sure its the same type - ie an array, if you are using the .map method.

Comment: Unrelated but might help you resolve issues later: Replace `console.log(data)` with `console.log(json)` . This way you wont get stale data and you will see the actual data that you fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data return from API is an `Object`, and there is no `map` method for the object, you can use `Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `Object.keys` to iterate over an object.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const apiCall = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json);
      });
  };
  console.log(data);
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{
    data ? Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => <div><span>{ key }:</span><span>{ JSON.stringify(value) }</span></div>) : null
  }</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit apiCall (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

The data you're getting from `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1` is an **object**, not array. You cannot only apply `map` method on an **Object**. Read about map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

I edit your code to :
you get this error because data is a `object` not an array

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const apiCall = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json); // json is object not array
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  if (data) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <h2>{data.id}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
}
```